# Using JQuery Tablesorter, with child rows and reloading child rows with ajax

Tags: jquery, parent-child, tablesorter

So I'm using jquery.tablesorter.js 2.0 which is fine.  However, I have added child rows now, which means in order to keep the sort working I also have to use jquery.tablesorter.mod.js which provides a mechanism for making child rows stick to parent rows when sorting.  This also works as advertised.

The problem is that I need to be able to dynamically refresh these child rows with ajax because the child rows are used to display either existing notes or a new note row.  When the user types in a new note, the save refreshes the row and returns it as an existing note.  When an existing comment is deleted, the save refreshes the row so that the deleted note disappears.

To help picture what I'm trying to do here this is what the table looks like with an existing note for the child row.

[image]

In order to accomplish this dynamic refreshing of these rows I have had to wrap them in <tbody> tags, as it seems I can only refresh the *content* of an element, not the element itself.  So the row is the content of the tbody.

Without the row sorting, this dynamic refresh of the rows works great.  And without the dynamic refresh of the rows, the table sorting works great.  Can anybody give me any insight into how I might be able to make it all work together?

If I can use jquery ajax to refresh an entire table row without using <tbody> tags, that would make all my problems go away, but I am also open to modifying the tablesorter.js or tablesorter.mod.js or using a different table sorting script altogether.

This is what my basic HTML looks like for my table.

```
<table class=sortable>
  <thead><th>Column Header</th></thead>
  <tr><td>Parent Row</td></tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Child Row</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please note that when you add `<tr>` to a table not wrapped within a `<tbody>`, the browser automatically wraps then in a tbody. So in your HTML above, you would end up with two tbodies in that table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this by getting rid of the <tbody> tags and putting the content for the child "row" inside a <td> inside the row.  Like so.

```
<table class=sortable>
  <thead><th>Column Header</th></thead>
  <tr><td>Parent Row</td></tr>
  <tr><td id=childrow><div>blah blah blah</div></td></tr>
</table>
```

This way I can reload the contents of the <td> and not mess up the table dom with tbodies.